# How to query non-existing row on table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this following table:

| Subject | YYYYWW | Status | Marks |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| History | 2020W01 | PASS | 80 |
| Math | 2020W01 | PASS | 85 |
| History | 2020W02 | PASS | 92 |
| Math | 2020W02 | PASS | 89 |
| History | 2020W03 | FAILED | 50 |
| History | 2020W04 | PASS | 81 |
| Math | 2020W04 | PASS | 95 |

So my objective is to query on Math subject where it shows all the weekly marks like table below:

| Subject | YYYYWW | Status | Marks |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Math | 2020W01 | PASS | 85 |
| Math | 2020W02 | PASS | 89 |
| Math | 2020W03 | NULL | NULL |
| Math | 2020W04 | PASS | 95 |

The current query I am using is:

`SELECT Subject, YYYYWW, Status, Marks FROM dbo.Test WHERE Subject = 'Math' AND Status = 'PASS' ORDER BY YYYYWW`

And I am getting this table:

| Subject | YYYYWW | Status | Marks |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Math | 2020W01 | PASS | 85 |
| Math | 2020W02 | PASS | 89 |
| Math | 2020W04 | PASS | 95 |

I am using SQL Server Management Studio 18.
Another note is I cannot edit or add data into the table.

What is the solution that you would recommend?

Comment: Can you please tag which database you are using?

Comment: Is the column `YYYYWW` a foreign key to another table? If this is the case, use a `JOIN`. The fact that you `NULL`s in your example solution suggests that.

Answer (score 1):

You may use a calendar table approach here to generate all week-years, then left join that to your current table:

```sql
SELECT
    'Math' AS Subject,
    t1.YYYYWW,
    t2.Status,
    t2.Marks
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT YYYYWW FROM dbo.Test) t1
LEFT JOIN dbo.Test t2
    ON t2.YYYYWW = t1.YYYYWW AND
       t2.Subject = 'Math';
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Note that a more general solution to this problem would involve a second calendar table for all subjects:

```
(SELECT DISTINCT Subject FROM dbo.Test)
```

We would then cross join this with the first calendar table for all week-years to get the grid for all subjects and week-years.  However, in this particular case, you only care about a single subject, so I chose to just select `'Math'` and avoid another join.

Comment: Would you elaborate more on this 'We would then cross join this with the first calendar table for all week-years to get the grid for all subjects and week-years.' statement? Thank you for your help

Comment: I have elaborated already, see the second half of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

One method is conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT 'Math' as Subject, YYYYWW,
       (CASE WHEN Subject = 'Math' AND Status = 'PASS' THEN Status END) as Status,
       (CASE WHEN Subject = 'Math' AND Status = 'PASS' THEN Marks END) as marks
FROM dbo.Test t
GROUP BY YYYYWW
```